# Pulling element/data from an external website with php and cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to pull in an element from an external website using **PHP** and **cURL**.

- The link to the website I'm trying to pull content from is:
  http://www.stayclassy.org/fundraise?fcid=231864
- The element I'm targeting is the number value under the list item
  "Raised So Far" in the right column at the top (right now the value is at $10).
- Here is the code I'm using to extract the data:

  ```
      define("TARGET", "http://www.stayclassy.org/fundraise?fcid=231864");
  ```

  `$curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, TARGET);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  if(!($results = curl_exec($curl))) {
      print("{ \"total\": \"$0.00\" }");
      return;
  } 

  $pattern = '/\<li class="goalTitle"\> \$(.+?) \<\/li\>\<\/a\>/';
  preg_match_all($pattern, $results, $matches);

  $total = $matches[1][0];
  $total = str_replace(",", "", $total);

  printf("{ \"total\": \"$%s\" }", formatMoney($total, true));


  function formatMoney($number, $fractional=false) 
  {
      if ($fractional) {
          $number = sprintf('%.2f', $number);
      }
      while (true) {
          $replaced = preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $number);
          if ($replaced != $number) {
              $number = $replaced;
          } else {
              break;
          }
      }
      return $number;
  }`

The issue I'm having is that the list item/element I'm targeting doesn't have a unique ID or class. In fact, the dollar amount is located in a separate list item without a class.

I was wondering how to target a specific list item in an unordered list using the code above, particularly when it doesn't have a class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Targeting the specific item requires that you identify a unique string around it. To do this you just expand further and further out until you find a string you can identify that only occurs once. So, the line you want is:

```
<li>$10</li>
```

but this is not unique at all. So we expand the string by adding the previous line as well:

```
<li class="goalTitle">Raised so far:</li>
<li>$10</li>
```

and bingo, this string is unique for your needs. The string is fairly constant except for your amount, so it will be easy to use. So you need a regular expression that finds this string. I'd use something like this:

```
$pattern = '/<li class="goalTitle">Raised so far:<\/li>\s*<li>\$(\d+)<\/li>/';
```

You don't need to use `preg_match_all` because you only expect to get one match:

```
preg_match($pattern, $results, $matches);
$total = $matches[1];
```

---

Your other options include loading the page with a `DOMDocument`, and then using `XPath` or `getElementById` to parse the DOM. But that may be a little too much effort for this task.

Also, I'd use `file_get_contents` to fetch the contents of the remote site. But that's just me.

---

**UPDATE:** To handle thousands separators as well, modify your pattern as follows:

```
$pattern = '/<li class="goalTitle">Raised so far:<\/li>\s*<li>\$([\d\.,]+)<\/li>/';
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks so much for taking the time to help! :)

Comment: Hey Gareth, is there a reason why it wouldn't return a number value greater than 3 digits? A total went to $1,000 and it returned the value $0.00. It would show $999, but wouldn't work anything more than that?

Comment: Yes - the thousands include a thousands separator that is not a number (in this case a comma). My answer has been updated.